# My Q still on hold though I edited it and clarified!

Tags: support, specific-question

May I know why this Q is still on hold although I edited it and clarified. Now the Q is too simple to understand. 1 day has passed since I edited but yet it's on hold. I had been waiting for some replies on that Q.

I have added a new tag as I haven't found any tag that corresponds to my Q.

Comment: can we have a link to your question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes five votes to reopen a question, and you'd only gotten three so far; traffic slows down quite a bit around Christmas. I reopened it, but Ubuntu-specific questions like this actually belong on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) (see the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), so I moved it there.

Comment: Thank you very much